# Apache Nifi put file on iSeries FTP

Tags: apache-nifi, ibm-midrange

**At this time, it isn't possible to interact with an iSeries IFS using Nifi. If this is something that you need, I recommend heading over and voting/commenting.**

[Opened an enhancement with ASF](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7553)

Edit:
I created a dynamic property pre.cmd._____ per a suggestion below and seem to still be having the same issue. Perhaps I'm not creating this correctly? I've tried quoting and a few other variations with no success:
[image]

Looking to use Apache Nifi (1.11.4) for some near real time file movements and one requirement of mine is to FTP a file to an FTP hosted on an iSeries.

An iSeries has two formats when utilizing FTP, NAMEFMT 0 when accessing libraries, physical files, and members, and NAMEFMT 1 when accessing the IFS. [More on that if you're interested...](https://www.mcpressonline.com/it-infrastructure-other/general/the-one-as400-ftp-command-you-must-understand)

I set up what I thought was a very simple process to get acquainted, detect when a file is placed on an SFTP, and simply move it on over to our iSeries:
[image: Nifi flow]

The problem I'm having is that I'm simply trying to place the file on the IFS in my home directory /home/dkorinke. However, the PutFTP is erroring as it seems to be using NAMEFMT 0 and when changing directory to /home/dkorinke.

From the logs:

`2020-06-10 21:09:36,924 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutFTP PutFTP[id=a084128f-0172-1000-49e1-fdd7b9d8d129] Unable to transfer StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=72600f74-2678-4c33-870a-f2648aac034b,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1591830969408-1, container=default, section=1], offset=463787, length=104801],offset=0,name=My_File.csv,size=104801] to remote host DEVQA01 due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Unable to change working directory to /HOME/DKORINKE/: null; routing to failure`

I began playing around with the Remote Path property on the PutFTP and was able to get a different error when using "/HOME/DKORINKE/". I noticed QGPL/ in front of "/HOME/DKORINKE":

`2020-06-10 21:53:35,710 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutFTP PutFTP[id=a084128f-0172-1000-49e1-fdd7b9d8d129] Unable to transfer StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=14303c7c-babb-4cbf-9728-346e0afaafba,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1591830969408-1, container=default, section=1], offset=882991, length=104801],offset=0,name=My_File.csv,size=104801] to remote host DEVQA01 due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Unable to change working directory to QGPL/"/HOME/DKORINKE/": null; routing to failure`

So far, the only solution I can think of is to update my user profile to default to NAMEFMT 1 which I'm not entirely sure is possible. I've hit the Google pretty hard this evening but I haven't been able to find anyone having a similar use case or issue like this.

Comment: Maybe try `site namefmt 1` in [pre.cmd._____](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutFTP/)

Comment: @nfgl Thanks for pointing that out, suppose I was pretty focused on the predefined properties. I wound up setting pre.cmd._____ using the plus icon on the properties tab and retried with similar results. I'll update my post to include what I tried.

Comment: It should be /home/dkorinke and that folder must be chown nifi:nifi in order for nifi processor to work on the directory.

Comment: can you get the full log of the ftp session in nifi, or sniff it with wireshark or something else ?

Comment: @steven-dfheinz I'm using a specific user on the PutFTP processor that does have access to my home directory.

Comment: @nfgl I'll poke around the UI and see if I can find more logs besides what I found in nifi-app*.log

Comment: @nfgl The most important bit of that doc page is "The command specified in the key will be executed before doing a put.". Since I'm not getting past the cd, it's not getting that far. I'm going to read through and see if there is a way to execute a script or some pretask of some kind.

Comment: What's surprising is that when ftping from windows cmd, the server automatically sets namefmt to 1 when the first cd is a cd to an absolute ifs path, maybe other conditions. Thats why I talked about Wireshark (or STRCNNTRC) to see what is done

Comment: I was actually able to get to the FTP logs on the iSeries, definitely connecting but falling short on the cd. I opened a Jira enhancement with ASF https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7553

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanting to close the loop on this for anyone looking to get this working.

Using Nifi v1.22.0 and an iSeries on V7R5M0, I was able to get a simple text file to be processed via FTP onto the iSeries.

[image]

[image]

This now seems to work pretty out of the box with Nifi now.